# SonarQube not working with coalesce operators (ex: ??)

Tags: c#, sonarqube

This codeblock is tagged in SonarQube rule "Conditionally executed blocks should be reachable"

```
// myObject is an instance of a class and IsActive is a boolean property
if (myObject?.IsActive ?? false) {...
```

Which, in my case, is functionally the same as:

```
if (myObject != null && myObject.IsActive)
```

Why is this being tagged by the SonarQube rule?